# I'm having trouble posting to a website using requests

Tags: python, request

```
import requests
url = "https://nextdoor.com/login/?ucl=1"
username = "myusename"
password = "password" 
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
```

How should I post to my next door account using `requests`?

Comment: Typo , tags, and rephrase

Answer (score 0):

Log in requests use the "POST" method, not the "GET" method. Use requests.post instead of requests.get

```
 r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

You can find syntax for this method in documentation.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

For what you're trying to do please consider using selenium, I've had to do similar things in the past and I found it easier.